# Write a script to remove a multi-statements UDF

Tags: sql

Unsure how to solve this. Tried DELETE [dbo].[ws2_multi_udf] but I get the error message...

Msg 216, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
Parameters were not supplied for the function 'dbo.ws2_multi_udf'.

Comment: Try ["drop function"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190290.aspx).

Comment: What are you trying to do?